# Proper procedure to modify an assigned variable

Tags: r, xts

Good Evening. I have code that requires creating new variable names. I am presently using the assign function. After I create my new desired data structure, i am having difficulty modifying it thereafter. I have read many times that storing the variable names in lists is the ideal process, but i am having trouble getting there.

This code simply attempts to add a year column to the NewVar xts object.

The larger scope would be to loop through multiple years and 2018 would be ultimately replaced by i.

Thank you!

```
xts1 <- xts(x=1:10, order.by=Sys.Date()-1:10)
xts2 <- xts(x=21:30, order.by=Sys.Date()-1:10)

NewName = "NewVar"

assign(NewName, xts1 - xts2)
assign(NewName$year, 2018) # this is the code that fails logically...
```

EDIT:

The desired outcome is to have the NewVar XTS object, a time series of 10 values, have an additional column that displays 2018 for each value.

Yes, I can just say NewVar$year <- 2018. But i need to access the assigned variable name within the global environment (NewVar), without explicity typing it. Is there a way to access the XTS Object NewVar using NewName, and then modify it? My method finds the vector, rather than the newly created XTS. THANKS!

Comment: Please show your expected outcome. The current outcome of `assign(NewName, xts1 - xts2)` is an xts object called `NewVar`. Also using `assign` for `xts1 - xts2` is the same as `NewVar <- xts1 - xts2`. But the last results in better readable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't use NewName["year"]=2018 directly?

**Edits:**
OK, not quite sure I get it. See if this works for you.

```
xts1 <- xts(x=1:10, order.by=Sys.Date()-1:10)
xts2 <- xts(x=21:30, order.by=Sys.Date()-1:10)

NewName = "NewVar"    

assign(NewName, xts(cbind(N=xts1 - xts2, year=2018)))
```

Comment: Thank you! This 100% worked. You were able to add the new column with one line of code rather than 2 lines. My intent of the post simply was, how to modify a variable in the global environment that had been created from assignment without calling the new name explicitly. IE can you modify NewVar, but by using NewName. Anyway, thank you very much.